# Laravel Lumen image validation is not working

Tags: php, laravel, apache, dependencies, lumen

I'm validating a request as an image, but crashes saying:

> "Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you
>   enable the php_fileinfo extension?)".

In `php.ini` I don't have a `extension=php_fileinfo`, but I do have a `extension=fileinfo` uncommented line (I see Lumen put this and other dependencies without the `'php_'`). I also try adding `extension=php_fileinfo`, but when I restart Apache from XAMPP it crashes because it doesn't find that dependency. What should I do?

The code:

```
function updateProfilePicture(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);
//...
```

The php.ini section where fileinfo dependency is:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename
;
; For example:
;
;   extension=mysqli
;
; When the extension library to load is not located in the default extension
; directory, You may specify an absolute path to the library file:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/mysqli.so
;
; Note : The syntax used in previous PHP versions ('extension=<ext>.so' and
; 'extension='php_<ext>.dll') is supported for legacy reasons and may be
; deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please
; move to the new ('extension=<ext>) syntax.
;
; Notes for Windows environments :
;
; - Many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) or ext/ (PHP 5+)
;   extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5+).
;   Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
```

Maybe is it related to that disclaimer about how to set the dependencies directives? (I'm not sure because `extension=fileinfo` was already in the file as a default)
I'm using windows 10 and I found the file in `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_fileinfo.dll`

Comment: have you tried with .dll at the end, like this "extension=php_fileinfo.dll" ?

Comment: yes, and it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had another php.ini file with the commented line `;extension=fileinfo` in `C:\php\php.ini` (the one I was opening was in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`). Now I restarted Apache and it's working!